# Import Jaxws cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, jersey

Writing a sample rest web service using jersey, spring and maven. below is my pom.xml. Facing the issue Import Jaxws cannot be resolved. None of the jars are getting downloaded. New to spring maven and jersey. Any help appreciated.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ecb</groupId>
  <artifactId>ecbWS</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
        <jersey.version>2.2</jersey.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>2.3</javax.servlet.version>
        <spring.batch.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
                <version>6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.51</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-simple</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-declarative-linking</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What have you done to try and download the dependencies?

Comment: I have done nothing to download dependency. What should be done?

Comment: try this dependencies http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey

Comment: dependencyManagement only registers information about each dependency so they can be referred to elsewhere without version or scope.  You need a dependencies section in your build segment.

Comment: If you have Maven installed you can run `mvn package` (from the project root, where the pom file should be). If you are in an IDE, make sure the IDE has Maven support and you actually have the correct Maven project structure, then just build it the project.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yup, good catch :-)

Comment: You should remove the `<dependencyManagement>` wrapper element around the `<dependencies>` as @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen mentioned. Then build the project

Comment: dependencyManagement is to specify the dependencies only, like for a parent project... But doesn't download anything... So, @peeskillet that would fix it

Comment: Yes removing <dependencyManagement> fixed it. But now facing issue missing artifact jersey-declarative-linking jar 2.2. commenting the dependency would solve it. But what actually missing artifact issue here?

Comment: The artifact does not exist. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-declarative-linking